# Links em menu strip

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

É possível colocar o link para algum site no Menu Strip do Windows Forms?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código no click do meu menu, porém não abre o link.

```
private void menuSobre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.Document.Window.Open("http://www.meusite.com.br","_blank", "location", true);
}
```

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você quer clicar no menu e abrir o browser pra ir pro endeço?

Comment: Sim @jbueno. Isso mesmo que eu quero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nativamente isso não existe, mas é relativamente simples trabalhar numa solução usando a classe [**`Process`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) e o evento de click do `MenuItem`.

Desde que os links comecem com **http://** o `Process.Start()` vai abrir o navegador padrão direto neste endereço.

É importante lembrar de incluir o namespace `System.Diagnostics`.

Veja:

```
private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (ToolStripItem)sender;
    var link = menuItem.Text;

    Process.Start(link);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou desse jeito. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Até onde sei, nativamente você não consegue fazer com que isso vire um link de fato, mas você pode fazer pelo código para a sua aplicação abrir o navegador com essa URL.

Ex:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
```

[Post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425381/launch-a-url-from-a-winforms-app)